# Query results in nested DTO

Tags: spring-data

Are nested DTOs in JPQL queries not allowed in Spring Data ? :

```
@Query("SELECT new test.customresult.CategoryCounter(c.name, " 
        + "new test.customresult.CarResult(COUNT(e.category), e.category)"
        + "FROM error e JOIN e.car c  "
        + "GROUP BY c.name,e.category")
List<CategoryCounter>countErrors();
```

Because, I get the following error message when trying to use the above mentioned JPQL query :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: , near line 1,
```

I want to return such a JSON file from the JPQL query :

```
[{
        "Car 1": 
        [{
                "count": 1,
                "category": "A"
            }, {
                "count": 2,
                "category": "B"
            }, {
                "count": 0,
                "category": "C"
            }, {
                "count": 0,
                "category": "D"
            }
        ]

    }, {
        "Car 2": 
        [{
                "count": 0,
                "category": "A"
            }, {
                "count": 0,
                "category": "B"
            }, {
                "count": 4,
                "category": "C"
            }, {
                "count": 5,
                "category": "D"
            }
        ]

    }
]
```

There is a **car** table and an **error** table which contains the categories and a foreign key to the car table.

I wanted to use the nested DTO to represent the desired output :

**The "wrapper" DTO**

```
public class CategoryCounter {

    private String name;
    private CarResult carResult ;

    public CategoryCounter (String name, CarResult carResult ) {

        this.name= name;
        this.carResult = carResult ;
    }


    public CarResult getCarResult () {
        return carResult ;
    }

    public void setCarResult(CarResult carResult ) {
        this.carResult = carResult ;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }

}
```

**and the "nested" DTO :**

```
public class CarResult {


    private Long count;
    private String category;

    public CarResult (Long count, String category) {

        this.count = count;
        this.category= category;
    }


    public Long getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(Long count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category= category;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this could be the problem... but you have your FROM clause starting immediately after the `)` it says:

```
+ "new test.customresult.CarResult(COUNT(e.category), e.category)"
+ "FROM error e JOIN e.car c  "
```

that is the same to: `e.category)FROM` so put a space in that part and try again...

```
+ "new test.customresult.CarResult(COUNT(e.category), e.category)"
+ " FROM error e JOIN e.car c  "
```

the thing is that the error (Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException) is a **syntax error**

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I put a space in the field where you suggested. But unfortunately, still showing the same error message and it is pointing right after the comma in  **c.name, new**